# What are the color values for dyed wool?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm looking to make some art in Minecraft with colored wool, and I want to use Illustrator to pixelize my pictures.  It would be very helpful if I could make a color palette of the available colors.  So, does anyone have a list of the available colors?  Hex is preferred, but RGB and CMYK will work too.

Comment: I would think that the colors that you actually see in game would depend on lighting and distance (due to distance fog)

Comment: Hmm, good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably not going to be exact, but I found this:

```
 • White      - FFe4e4e4 
 • Light Gray - FFa0a7a7 
 • Dark Gray  - FF414141 
 • Black      - FF181414 
 • Red        - FF9e2b27 
 • Orange     - FFea7e35 
 • Yellow     - FFc2b51c 
 • Lime Green - FF39ba2e 
 • Green      - FF364b18 
 • Light Blue - FF6387d2 
 • Cyan       - FF267191 
 • Blue       - FF253193 
 • Purple     - FF7e34bf 
 • Magenta    - FFbe49c9 
 • Pink       - FFd98199 
 • Brown      - FF56331c
```

The colors are in hexadecimal code, the leading FF byte representing opacity. Since the colors in game are varied, these were [derived from images of the wool texture and averaged over an 11-pixel area in Photoshop](http://teaminterrobang.com/showthread.php?35959-Minecraft-wool-color-Photoshop-ACO-file).

Comment: That's hex, right?  Is the leading FF the opacity?

Comment: @andronikus I do believe that to be correct, yes.

Comment: Minecraft wools aren't one solid color. Is this the most *common* pixel, or what?

Comment: @RavenDreamer These were ["derived from images of the wool texture and averaged over an 11-pixel area in Photoshop"](http://teaminterrobang.com/showthread.php?35959-Minecraft-wool-color-Photoshop-ACO-file).  I personally tried every single one and they looked very close to me.

Comment: @andronikus You're welcome!  :)